# How to increase the MaxPermSize on the OpenShift environment? I am having trouble starting the jboss

Tags: deployment, jboss, openshift, java-opts

I am new to OpenShift, and I am having trouble deploying my application, and it seems to be because I don't have enough MaxPermSize, which is set to 102m.

When I start the jboss I have this type of logs, loading the various services.

> 2014/12/30 10:13:37,806 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC
>   service thread 1-3) MSC000001: Failed to start service
>   jboss.jacorb.poa-service.rootpoa: org.jbo
>   ss.msc.service.StartException in service
>   jboss.jacorb.poa-service.rootpoa: Failed to start service
>           at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1936)
>   [jboss-msc.jar:1.1.5.Final-redhat-1]
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71] Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native
>   thread
>           at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
>           at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:714) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
>           at org.jacorb.poa.AOM.(AOM.java:135)
>           at org.jacorb.poa.POA.configure(POA.java:273)
>           at org.jacorb.orb.ORB.getRootPOA(ORB.java:1035)
>           at org.jacorb.orb.ORB.resolve_initial_references(ORB.java:1307)
>           at org.jboss.as.jacorb.service.CorbaPOAService.start(CorbaPOAService.java:153)
>           at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1980)
>   [jboss-msc.jar:1.1.5.Final-redhat-1]
>           at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1913)
>   [jboss-msc.jar:1.1.5.Final-redhat-1]
>           ... 3 more

Like I said on the begginning, my guess is that I neeed to increase the JAVA_OPTS setting MaxPermSize to 256m or 512m. Can anyone help me do that on the OpenShift cenario?

Regards,
Emil Xavier

Answer (score 0):

Openshift is a Cloud Platform.So Openshift will be provide dedicated server to you and there you might be have JBoss setup.

Just goto $JBOSS_HOME/bin/standalone.conf

Update your maxPermSize there.

Ex  : `JAVA_OPTS=-Xms1303M -Xmx1303M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M`

Also you can update maxPermSize through each node wise and each group wise.

Comment: I don't think Openshift allows you to change that variable anywhere. The solution I found was to set the JAVA_OPT_EXT variable, which openshift rhc command line tools do allow you to change by setting it before the jboss start, like this: 
rhc env-set JAVA_OPTS_EXT="-XX:MaxPermSize=256m" --app jbossas

I have tried that, still, I'm not sure it worked because on the start of the jboss, the log still shows the MaxPermSize being picked up as 102m. And though my problem has been resolved, that might have been because I've changed the openshift container I used from JBOSS EAP 6.1 to JBOSS AS 7.

Comment: Hello... You have completed access in JBOss server which as equal to your local machine with limited memory. Openshift provides free tier with minimum memory.

Comment: Yes, still, they state that we are provided with up to 512m (free), and the default configuration was at 102m. That's why I thought I could increase it.